# How to defer parsing of javascript from the facebook page plugin?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, facebook, deferred

in my GTMetrix rating (https://gtmetrix.com/reports/um180grad.de/Z5fQRsag) it says that the parsing of javascript should be deferred for resources that are loaded inside the Facebook page plugin.

E.g.:

```
    https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yS/r/26fwJhqLaJ4.js (220.9KiB)
    https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yX/r/y50fApjV6bw.js (129.8KiB)
   https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yX/r/y50fApjV6bw.js (129.8KiB)
    https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yA/r/qTOnSmrXUMu.js (91.7KiB)
    https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yA/r/qTOnSmrXUMu.js (91.7KiB)
```

I have already deferred my local resources with the WP Deferred Javascript WordPress Plugin.

Is there any way to achieve this for the Facebook Scripts?

The same questions holds true for the GTMetrix message "Specify image dimensions" - I cannot change the image dimensions of the embedded facebook profile pics.

The Facebook page plugin loads an iframe, by the way.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: No, there isn’t anything you can to to influence how the FB social plugins work in that regard.

Answer (score -2):

You can use graph api for changing the dimentions of the facebook profile image.

```
graph.facebook.com/{user's FB ID}/picture?width=100&height=100
```

Comment: but the users that show up in the page plugin are mostly random.